# How do i fix error "A default export must be at the top level of a file or module decleration" in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I am getting this error when trying to scramble a word in vue.js using "shuffle" from the lodash library. This is the code that is causing the issue.

```
import { shuffle } from 'lodash'

// Get word of the day
const answer = getWordOfTheDay();

// scramble word of the day
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      word: answer,
      scrambledWord: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    scrambleWord(word) {
      return shuffle(word.split('')).join('')
    }
  }
}
```

I tried moving the block of code around and changing the order of things but i still get the same error. highlighted on the the "export default" part.

Comment: Is this your whole file?

Comment: Can't see any error. Can you provide the full file code?

Comment: i managed to fix the error myself.

Comment: please include what the answer is for future readers

Answer (score 11):

In case someone is wondering, one of the most common reasons this happens is when the attribute "setup" is left in the script tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it worked for me, but I would like to know what is that setup, due to which the export breaks.

Comment: Here's documentation on `<script setup>` https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#using-custom-directives

Answer (score 1):

removing the `setup` attribute in the `script` tag solve the issue for me.